# How to use style sheet component on all component in React native

Tags: react-native

i want to import style sheet component index.js file and use in all component 
because i want CSS for All Application Component

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create a file for your styles as `style.js` or as `index.js` as you mentioned

**Example**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20
  }
});
```

Than you can import this file in your required files as

```
import styles from './Style'
```